# Wine LedshowTW 2016

Tags: linux, debian, wine

Друзья, есть такая утилита, как LedshowTW 2016, которая позволяет управлять досками бегущей строки. Она написана только под Windows. Пытался запустить под Wine, но появляется куча ошибок в терминале. Вот собственно лог:

```
wine LedshowTW.exe 
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:msi:ready_media cabinet not found: L"C:\\users\\alexey\\Application Data\\ONBON\\LedshowTW 2016 16.08.16.0\\install\\disk1.cab"
err:msi:ACTION_InstallFiles Failed to ready media for L"BkgrdCustom"
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallFiles" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
```

Помогите запустить это уг. Не хочу в Windows возвращаться.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала `sudo apt install samba winbind`, чтобы решить проблему с `ntlm_auth` и затем убедитесь в корректности пути "C:\\users\\alexey\\Application Data\\ONBON\\LedshowTW 2016 16.08.16.0\\install\\disk1.cab".

Comment: А потом пробросьте ком-порты для управления через `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dos_devices/COM5` и добавьте пользователя в группы uucp и dialout